# Why? Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

I have this global axios setting:

```
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true
```

then following `useEffect` will raise error in title:

```js
    useEffect(() => {
        const initAuth = async (): Promise<void> => {
            setIsInitialized(true)
            setLoading(true)
            await axios
                .get(authConfig.meEndpoint, {
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                        crossDomain: true,
                    },
                })
                .then(async (response) => {
                    setLoading(false)
                    setUser({ ...response.data })
                })
                .catch(() => {
                    /*localStorage.removeItem('userData')
                    localStorage.removeItem('refreshToken')
                    localStorage.removeItem('accessToken')
                    setUser(null)*/
                    setLoading(false)
                })
        }
        initAuth()
    }, [])
```

and the stored session is not sent as cookie, why?

[image]

Comment: You're using NextJS, right? Anyways, this is likely because your endpoint has a bug that, after sending a response to the user, attempts to alter it if the request is sent with credentials.

Comment: Not react related, the error is at the backend

Comment: I think it more like a frontend issue, why Cookie is not send with GET message?

Comment: Please show us the code for the API endpoint you're making a request to.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is due to the fact that your front and back are separated by different domains, locally, for example, the front is localhost, the back 127.0.0.1 is considered different domains. In this case, cookies are not seted and are not actually sent (because there are none). to set the front cookie, you need to change domains to one (localhost:3000, localhost:3001), or add some flags to cookie-set header: SameSite: false, Secure: true (locally goes by default)

Comment: Yes, on different domain. I have the `crossDomain: true` and `withCredentials = true` flags. Those are needed, but maybe something overwrite one?!

Comment: the thing is that in order for you to send cookies from the front to the back using withCredentials, you need to first install these cookies by response header from the back

Comment: Yes, but before authentication cookie will not exist, but still it should not raise this error